# How do I solve npm install issue after deleting node_modules

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I am trying to clean out my react-native project's package to do a clean npm install on a MacOS based system (my windows system for Android  development has no issues in cleaning up package versions).

I started seeing errors in the npm instals complaining version differences betwces are not compatible and list differences between versions of each package in "rook project" and node_modules/  directory.

I do the usual fix  by removing package-lock.json, delete the node_modules directory and re-run npm install. from my project folder.   It immediately made the same error complaints.   The problem is this,  there is no node_modules in my project folder as I deleted it.   And it did not create a new node_modules directory.

Given this issue,  how do I debug this and fix it?     Questions I'd like to find out:

1. how do I tell npm to tell me what it thinks root project value is (full path)?
2. How to tell npm to tell me where the full path to the node_modules directory it seems to see?
3. Finally, how do I force npm to do the right thing and focus my my project's collaterals and not look outside the project folder as it appears to be doing?

Some of my thoughts.  I don't understand why it is making a package cersion comparison between root project and node_modules?

Seems that nodde and npm are doing different things in MacOS environment than in my windows system environment -- I don't understand this.

Anyone here can help me understand what is going on and how to  solve it?

The Error output here:

```
thomas@Presonus americanaradio % npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: AmericanaRadio@0.0.2
npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^16.13.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8" from
@react-native-community/async-storage@1.12.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/async-storage@"^1.12.1" from the
root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.2" from react-native@0.66.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"^0.66.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native@">=0.59" from
@react-native-community/async-storage@1.12.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/async-storage@"^1.12.1" from the
root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency
resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /Users/thomas/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/thomas/.npm/_logs/2021-12-10T15_47_02_669Z-debug.log
thomas@Presonus americanaradio %
```

The package.json content here:

```
{END)
 "name": "AmericanaRadio",
 "version": "0.0.2",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
   "android": "react-native run-android",
   "ios": "react-native run-ios",
   "start": "react-native start",
   "test": "jest",
   "lint": "eslint ."
 },
 "dependencies": {
   "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
   "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.2",
   "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
   "@react-native-community/slider": "^3.0.3",
   "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
   "react": "^16.13.1",
   "react-native": "^0.66.3",
   "react-native-background-timer": "^2.4.1",
   "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
   "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
   "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
   "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
   "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
   "react-native-screens": "^2.15.2",
   "react-native-simple-survey": "^3.1.2",
   "react-native-swift": "^1.2.1",
   "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.0.0",
   "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.2",
   "react-native-version-info": "^1.1.0",
   "react-native-webview": "^11.3.1",
   "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
   "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.6.0",
   "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.2",
   "react-usestateref": "^1.0.8",
   "socket.io-client": "^4.4.0"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
   "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
   "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
   "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
   "eslint": "^7.18.0",
   "jest": "^26.6.3",
   "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
   "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
 },
 "jest": {
   "preset": "react-native"
 }
}
~
(END)
```

As noted in my description, the node_modules directory was deleted and running npm install failed and did not create a nodes_modules directory.  So the error messages are confusing as I  have no packages in my project directory (americanaradio).

Thank you for taking a look at this and hopefully a solution can come out of ths.

Comment: you should list the errors that you are getting at `npm install`

Comment: You shouldn't be deleting the package-lock.json, it keeps exactly what dependencies were actually installed.

Comment: please attach error log details with your question

Answer (score 0):

First check what library is giving you an error and try to reinstall or update that version . Try deleting node modules also . Then do npm install.

Comment: Thanks for the  suggestions.  As noted in the body above,  I already made clear that I've deleted node-modules and ran npm install -- this is tylically a standard process.   But looking at the library is a good suggestion.  I see some other ideas like deleting the .react-native-cli folder that exist in the home directory which contains copies of the projects.   Still debugging....